# Why doesn't the ENS public resolver support IP address resolution?

Tags: ens, dns, resolver

I wondered if there are any well-considered reasons behind the decision to not support a standardized record for IP addresses (e.g. A/AAAA records by IETF) [through the public resolver](https://docs.ens.domains/contract-api-reference/publicresolver) and the offical dApp, even though mentioned in the [orignal EIP 137](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-137).

Suspicion: Is it because of a vision for the web3 where resources are usually accessed by their hash?